# How to access translation key for ActiveModel validation error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activemodel

I Have a situation, where I wan't to store the translation key for a validation error in my db instead of the error message it self. Imagine the following situation:

```
class Car < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_presence_of :year, :fuel
end

car = Car.new(:fuel => 'Diesel')
car.save!
#=> ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid
```

Now if I call:

```
car.errors
#=> :year=>["can't be blank"]
```

I get the translated error message.

Instead I would like to extract the translation key that would generate this (in this case I think it would be something like `errors.messages.blank`), so I can store it in my database in a different model e.g. `FailedCar` so I can later on generate an I18n customized form for filling in the missing information manually in a view.

**UPDATE**

I think it's [this](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/3d0c0c6c95f8ed35c3fea79cfe93ec6e74f726ec/activemodel/lib/active_model/errors.rb#L405) method that I need to hook into. I want to fetch the key and the options returned, so I can perform the translations again at a later point in time.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Okay I finally got it!

The solution is NOT to patch or do anything on the rails side of things - instead - the answer lies in the `I18n` gem.

I18n, which rails uses for translations by standard, has the ability to plugin new backends to provide more flexibility to it. In this case, the backend called [metadata](https://github.com/svenfuchs/i18n/blob/master/lib/i18n/backend/metadata.rb) does exactly what I needed. When adding `I18n::Backend::Simple.include(I18n::Backend::Metadata)` to an initializer, it gives me the possibility of extracting all translation related information directly from the error message string by adding the method call `translation_metadata`.

A fantastic simple solution to a complicated problem :-)

Comment: This is neat! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at (.yml) local files too? You can store it as a translation string. For more Info [Rails Internationalization](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html).